# skimage.io.imread behaving differently when giving a string or Path

Tags: python, scikit-image, imread, pathlib

I just stumbled upon a weird situation with `skimage.io.imread`.

I was trying to open a MultiPage TIFF (dimensions: 96x512x512) like this:

```
import argparse
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
from skimage import io

def numpy_array_from_file(path):
    """ method to load numpy array from tiff file"""
    im_data = io.imread(path)
    print ("image dimensions {}".format(im_data.shape))
    return im_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Extract page from a MultiPage TIFF")
    parser.add_argument("tiff_file", type=str, help="3D TIFF file to open)")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    tiff_file = Path(args.tiff_file).absolute()
    numpy_array_from_file(tiff_file)
```

And I was obtaining in the output:

```
image dimensions (512, 512)
```

After trying many different things (because I was sure that my input image had 96 pages), I discovered that the problem was to use directly `Path` in the `numpy_array_from_file` instead of using a string. By changing the last line to:

```
    numpy_array_from_file(str(tiff_file))
```

I got the expected:

```
image dimensions (96, 512, 512)
```

So, my question is ... Anyone know why I had that behaviour? I am not very experienced in python, but I would have expected to obtain an error if `Path` was not appropriate in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `pathlib.Path` is relatively new, so support in scikit-image is generally patchy. What's happening is that, because the `Path` is not a string, the extension isn't checked, and `imageio` is used instead of `tifffile`. The behavior of `imread` is different for the two libraries, with `imageio` preferring to only return a single plane.

This is a known issue [in our issue tracker](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/4138). Until it's fixed, you can use `str()` or explicitly call `plugin='tifffile'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! At some point I thought my python skills were getting rusty, but it was not my fault after all :)